# Extension Method C# ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this extension method and I have a problem when I call it in my startup class:

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
        public static void ConfigureMySqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var connectionString = config["mysqlconnection:connectionString"];
            services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        }
}
```

And this in startup class - I get an error to add IServiceCollection (.NET Core 6)

```
ServiceExtensions.ConfigureMySqlContext(builder.Configuration);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community  the extension method not working !! (this) key not recognized

Comment: Firstly, you need invoke method in Program.cs if you use .NET 6. Your extension method contains two parameters, so you need invoke it like: `ServiceExtensions.ConfigureMySqlContext(builder.Services,builder.Configuration);`.

Answer (score 7):

You are calling this extension in the wrong way. Since it is an "Extension" method, you need to invoke it on the concrete object, it is extending. By using the `this` keyword, you are extending the type you are invoking this method on by a specific functionality, without deriving from with a custom type.

```
services.ConfigureMySqlContext(builder.Configuration);
```

or, if you are basing your code off of the .net 6 minimal templates:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.ConfigureMySqlContext(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods